How can I execute JavaScript with nodriver python?
I'm trying to write some Python code, but I'm encountering some issues. For example, I can log in to a Cloudflare-protected site using nodriver, and I'm able to print the values of the elements on the page. However, my goal is to change these values or execute JavaScript code from the console (either option would be fine).
Note: Is there any other way to bypass Cloudflare? I've already tried undetected-chromedriver, but it wasn’t successful in bypassing it. I'm also looking for a way to execute console scripts or change values.
This is for executing a script (I thought ChatGPT might know).
import keyboard
import asyncio
import nodriver as uc
from time import sleep

url = "https://example.com/"

async def main():
    # Nodriver ile sayfa aç
    driver = await uc.start()
    
    tab = await driver.get(url)
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('g'):
            script = """
            document.title = 'New Topic';
            """
            driver.execute_script(script) 

asyncio.run(main())


You can refer to nodriver documentation for executing javascript or other related queries.
You can use Tab.evaluate instead of driver.execute_script for executing JavaScript.
The code below should work:
import keyboard
import asyncio
import nodriver as uc
from time import sleep

url = "https://example.com/"

async def main():
    # Nodriver ile sayfa aç
    driver = await uc.start()
    
    tab = await driver.get(url)
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('g'):
            script = """
            document.title = 'New Topic';
            """
            await tab.evaluate(script)

asyncio.run(main())

